# visual studio dont compile typescript to js file

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I have created an sharepoint add-in project, I crated "tsconfig.json" file solution then edit with configuration info and created a folder("app") and added new item(app.module.ts) into that folder.

after than I build solution, there is no error in build and I expected to see generated js files(app.module.js and app.module.js.map) from ts file in the project but nothing occurs.

here is my solution explorer:
[image]

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "./Scripts"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
export class Welcome {
    public static getMessage() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I followed steps exactly I see in a tutorial he says file generated after build but I cant see any in my project.. how can I fix this ? more important how can I find detect problem here

referance:[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnQy3Hgl7lE) jump to 33:30

Comment: I am sorry, could you add a reference to your mentioned tutorial please?

Comment: @Inferon its done

Comment: Did you try clicking the "show all files" button in solution explorer or going to the directory? Maybe the files are just not being shown

Comment: of course I did, I also checked within file explorer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its strange but this because I added typescript project to project extarnally, since it was a sp project at first I would need to arrange .csproj manually;

I have changed

> None Include="tsconfig.json" />

to

> Content Include="tsconfig.json" />

and it works fine now..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in the solution explorer all files are visible, by clicking that little button "Show All Files" in the Solution Explorer. By default the .js and .js.map files are not added to the solution, only exported to that outDir, similar to .dll files.

If you are under source control like Team Foundation Server from visualstudio.com your published .js files will not be added to TFS automatically. You need to initially add them the first time. You do this by right-clicking the files and include to project. (Make sure "Show All Files" is enabled in Solution Explorer).